# Angular - Any reason why updating scope would cause page scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular is there any reason why updating a `$scope` variable would cause my page to scroll to the top?

Simply, the variable i am updating is `$scope.searchResults` however each time its updated, the page scrolls to the top.

```
if ($routeParams.textToSearch == 'new') {

        getService.getResults('EU', 50)
        .then(function (data){
          $scope.searchResults = data.data[0];
        });

    }
```

Any ideas?

Detailed HTML as requested - this is in my `<ng-view autoscroll="true"></ng-view>`: (note I have tried autoscroll at false as well - issue still persists .

```
<div equalizer="'group'" " ng-repeat="question in searchResults">

<div class="searchTile" equalizer="'group'">

        <div id="circle{{$index}}">
          <nvd3 options="circleOptions" data="question.options"></nvd3>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an ng-repeat in your code. Whenever you update your data, the ng-repeat has to delete then recreate its part of the page. So the page shrinks and regrows. So if appears that it scrolled to the top.

Adding a track by to the ng-repeat may help as it will then recognise that most of the cells are the same so keep them in the DOM, which should stop all the rows being destroyed when they match.

Comment: Ahhhh - that makes sense. I'm thinking I should choose an element ID and scroll to that instead - whats your view on that.

Comment: I just placed in `ng-repeat="question in searchResults track by $index"` and the page remains :) - just to confirm this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, hopefully that is what you needed.